# How to center links in the navigation bar with CSS3 an HTML5?

Tags: html, css, nav, centering

I'm having trouble to center the links in the navigation bar,
because I want the buttons to be in the center of the header bar,
but trying everything, so far they always remain on the left

```css
    .header {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .header a {
    float: left;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .header a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
    }

    .header a.active {
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    color: black;
    }
```

```html
    <header>
        <nav class="header">
            <a href="#default" class="logo">CompanyLogo</a>
            <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
        </nav>  
    </header>
```

Thanks to anyone who will help me!

Answer (score 0):

use flex.  it's a lot easier

```css
.header{
display:flex;
justify-content:space-evenly;}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav class="header">
        <a href="#default" class="logo">CompanyLogo</a>
        <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
    </nav>  
</header>
```

Comment: `justify-content: center;` was maybe what the OP was looking for, I think.

Comment: that will just bunch them together unless we add margin or padding. The main point is use FLEX!

Answer (score 0):

- use `flex` box it is really a nicer way to center elements horizontally and vertically so here is my solution depend on `flex`

```
.header {
background-color: #f1f1f1;
padding: 10px 20px;
border-radius: 5px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

.header a {
color: black;
text-align: center;
padding: 12px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 25px;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.header a:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
color: black;
}

.header a.active {
background-color: #e1e1e1;
color: black;
}
```